# VueJs router-link not working, but link copied from it works in another tab

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, routerlink

I am building an webapp with VueJs. I have three pages, apps, registries, identities. In the apps page there is a table with apps with a **link1** *(localhost:8080/apps/{appid}/regs)* to view it's registry in each row. Similarly in registry page, there is a **link2** 
*(localhost:8080/apps/{appid}/regs/{regid}/ids)* to view it's app.

My problem is, when I click on **link1** it takes me to the registries page, but when I click on **link2** it takes me to *localhost:8080* in stead of *localhost:8080/apps/{appid}/regs/{regid}/ids*. But when I copy the address from **link2** and paste in address bar it takes me to the desired page. What am I doing wrong?

Also I am getting following warning in the console -

> [Vue warn] missing param for named route "regs": Expected "appid" to
>   be defined
>
> [Vue warn] missing param for named route "ids": Expected "appid" to be
>   defined

**router.js**

```
{
    path: "apps",
    name: "apps",
    component: () => import("./components/protected/Apps"),
},
{
    path: "apps/:appid/regs",
    name: "regs",
    props: true,
    component: () => import("./components/protected/Regs"),
},
{
    path: "apps/:appid/regs/:regid/ids",
    name: "ids",
    props: true,
    component: () => import("./components/protected/Ids"),
},
```

**Apps.vue**

```
<template>
<table class="table table-striped mg-b-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="tx-left w-5">#</th>
            <th class="tx-left">Application</th>
            <th class="tx-left text-center w-5">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-bind:key="index" v-for="(app, index) in apps">
            <td class="masked">{{index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{app.name}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <router-link class="bg-white" :to="{ name: 'regs', params: { appid: app.id}}">
                    <i class="fa fa-border fa-eye" title="View Registries"/>
                </router-link>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</template>
```

**Regs.vue**

```
<template>
<template v-if="appid">
<table class="table table-striped mg-b-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="tx-left w-5">#</th>
            <th class="tx-left">Registry</th>
            <th class="tx-left text-center w-5">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-bind:key="index" v-for="(reg, index) in regs">
            <td class="masked">{{index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{reg.name}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <router-link class="bg-white" :to="{ name: 'ids', params: { appid: appid, regid: reg.id}}">
                    <i class="fa fa-border fa-eye" title="View Identities"/>
                </router-link>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</template>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "Regs",
    props: ['appid'],
    ....
}
```

**Ids.vue**

```
<template>
<template v-if="appid && regid">
<table class="table table-striped mg-b-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="tx-left w-5">#</th>
            <th class="tx-left">Identity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-bind:key="index" v-for="(id, index) in ids">
            <td class="masked">{{index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</template>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "Ids",
    props: ['appid','regid'],
    ....
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that your variable `appid` (which is assigned through a property) does not actually have a value. Instead it should be `$router.params.appid`

Comment: Yes, appid is indeed a router param

Comment: Yes. My point is that you're using: `:to="{ name: 'ids', params: { appid: appid, regid: reg.id}}"`. Where `appid` in this case will reference your `prop`. However, `props` are not hydrated by the router, so it should acutally be: `:to="{ name: 'ids', params: { appid: $router.params.appid, regid: reg.id}}"`

Comment: I am using https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html this documentation, and I think I have followed what they were trying to instruct. I also used your advise (should be $route in stead of $router I think), still same problem. Clicking on link landing me to localhost:8080 but copying link address and pasting it in address bar seems to work

Comment: Please check `Regs.vue`file. Are there `id` property in the `regs` data.

Comment: Or you can add the `v-if` to control the visible of the link to avoid the dirty data. Like the followings `<router-link v-if="reg.id" class="bg-white" :to="{ name: 'ids', params: { appid: appid, regid: reg.id}}">`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are already using the props appid' and 'regid' where the props are not yet fully ready in your component itself. Thats why the vue returned a warning.

You could put a condition first before you execute your vfor to ensure that the props has already a value. like this one

**Regs.vue**

```
 <template v-if="appid">
       <tr v-bind:key="index" v-for="(reg, index) in regs">
                <td class="masked">{{index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{reg.name}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <router-link class="bg-white" :to="{ name: 'ids', params: { appid: appid, 
                      regid: reg.id}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-border fa-eye" title="View Identities"/>
                    </router-link>
                </td>
       </tr>
</template>
```

**Ids.vue**

```
<template v-if="appid &&  regid">
    <tr v-bind:key="index" v-for="(id, index) in ids">
            <td class="masked">{{index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Tried that also, still getting the warning. Check my edit